# How to query a dynamodb2 index using boto?

Tags: boto

How can I query a dynamodb2 table with an index using boto? I'm not able to piece together enough information from the documentation or unit tests for boto.

I have a local index created as:

```
fields.KeysOnlyIndex('NameIndex', parts=[
    fields.HashKey('account_id', data_type='S'),
    fields.RangeKey('name', data_type='S'),
])
```

And would like to lookup an item using the `account_id` and `name`.

Attempting to make the call `table.query( account_id__eq=account['id'], name__eq = name )` results in the error `Query condition missed key schema element id`.

Note: I would also prefer to avoid using the `Table` class and work directly with the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with **Table**:

```
table = Table('accounts')
results = table.query(index='NameIndex', account_id__eq=account['id'], name__eq=name)
```

or with **Connection**:

```
results = conn.query(
    table_name='accounts',
    index_name='NameIndex', 
    select='ALL_PROJECTED_ATTRIBUTES', 
    key_conditions={
        'account_id': {
            'AttributeValueList': [
                {'S': account['id']},
            ],
            'ComparisonOperator': 'EQ',
        },
        'name': {
            'AttributeValueList': [
                {'S': name},
            ],
            'ComparisonOperator': 'EQ',
        },
    }
)
```